# SqlAlchemy InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I'm stuck on this and I'm not sure what's the problem. I have a many to many relationship between User and Address. I'm trying to create a page that displays all addresses for a user and users can be redirected to another page to edit their address information. I have two routes for that, user route only display addresses and provides the address_id to edit_address that deals with updating the info.

I keep getting this error :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: UPDATE addresses SET updated_at=?, address=?, country=?, city=?, post_code=? WHERE addresses.id = ?]
[parameters: ('2020-05-27 19:39:33.594937', ('testing',), ('gb',), ('london',), ('lo346bd',), 1)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)
```

My Models:

```
class TimestampMixin(object):
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False,
                           default=datetime.utcnow)
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, onupdate=datetime.utcnow)

user_addresses = db.Table('user_addresses',
                          db.Column("user_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
                              "users.id")),
                          db.Column("address_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("addresses.id")))

class User(db.Model, TimestampMixin, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    (...)
    # relationships (many to many)
    address = db.relationship("Address", secondary="user_addresses", backref="user", lazy="dynamic")

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}')"

class Address(db.Model, TimestampMixin):
    __tablename__ = "addresses"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    address = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    country = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    city = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    post_code = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Address('{self.id}', '{self.address}', '{self.country}', '{self.post_code}')"
```

My template:

```
<div class="container custom-bg my-4">
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="py-4">
    {{form.csrf_token()}}
    <div class="form-group col-12">
      {{render_field(form.address , class="form-control",placeholder="Enter your street address")}}
      {% for error in form.errors.address %}
      <div class="text-danger">{{error}}</div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-12">
      {{render_field(form.city , class="form-control",placeholder="Enter your city")}}
      {% for error in form.errors.city %}
      <div class="text-danger">{{error}}</div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-12">
      {{render_field(form.country , class="form-control",placeholder="Enter your country")}}
      {% for error in form.errors.country %}
      <div class="text-danger">{{error}}</div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-12">
      {{render_field(form.post_code , class="form-control",placeholder="Enter your post code")}}
      {% for error in form.errors.post_code %}
      <div class="text-danger">{{error}}</div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
      {{render_field(form.submit, class="btn btn-block btn-secondary")}}
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

My view

```
@ app.route("/profile/settings/edit_address/<address_id>", methods=["POST", "GET"])
@ login_required
def edit_address(address_id):

    addresses = Address.query.filter_by(id=address_id).first()
    form = UpdateAddressForm(obj=addresses)
    form.populate_obj(addresses)

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Update address
        addresses.address = form.address.data.lower(),
        addresses.city = form.city.data.lower(),
        addresses.post_code = form.post_code.data.lower(),
        addresses.country = form.country.data.lower(),

        db.session.commit()

        flash("You have updated your address!", "success")
        return redirect(url_for("user_settings"))

    return render_template("edit_address.html", title="Update Address", form=form)
```

Comment: Is that the extent of the error message or was there anything more?

Comment: This is the complete traceback: https://gist.github.com/Lucaas27/03dd8e87a522f23d64a206a8787ef5da

Comment: I've been stuck on this and I've found similar question but none that applied to my problem, I have tried several things but nothing works, I believe I'm getting a tuple back when getting the form data but I'm not sure why.

Comment: from the stack trace, it seems one of your input is of the wrong type. Have you tried inspecting you input types to make sure it conforms with your model? If that still does not fix it, and you have a reproducible git for the project. I can clone and further debug
@LucasGomes

Comment: The commas at the end  each line create tuples, they should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it after searching for hours. However, I'm still not sure why I was getting the error so if someone could claify it would be great. I believe it's something about the many to many relationship cause I use this same logic to update data with other relationships and never came across this. I was getting a tuple back from the data in the form which was then causing the error since it was expecting a string back. I'm not sure why this was happening. Anyway, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56319689/using-wtforms-populate-obj-to-update-many-to-many-association-table-with-extra-c) that helped me to adapt my view function and now it works.

```
@ app.route("/profile/settings/edit_address/<address_id>", methods=["POST", "GET"])
@ login_required
def edit_address(address_id):

address_to_update = Address.query.get(address_id)
form = AddressForm(obj=address_to_update)

if form.validate_on_submit():
    # Update address
    form.populate_obj(address_to_update)
    db.session.commit()

    flash("You have updated your address!", "success")
    return redirect(url_for("user_settings"))

return render_template("edit_address.html", title="Update Address", form=form)
```